# Display DNAME, LOC, DEPTNO of employees who has same MGR Using only JOINS

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

If i do this im getting the results but i want to do it with joins only.

```
SELECT DNAME, LOC, D.DEPTNO
  FROM EMP E, DEPT D
 WHERE E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO
   AND MGR IN (SELECT MGR FROM EMP GROUP BY MGR HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, you'd better using ANSI-92 JOIN syntax, instead of old-fashioned comma seperated format.*

This query

```
SELECT DNAME, LOC, D.DEPTNO
  FROM EMP E
  JOIN DEPT D ON E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO
  JOIN (SELECT MGR FROM EMP GROUP BY MGR HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) EE ON E.MGR = EE.MGR ;
```

is identical with yours. But if you don't want to return duplicated rows, this

```
SELECT DNAME, LOC, D.DEPTNO
  FROM EMP E
  JOIN DEPT D ON E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO
 GROUP BY DNAME, LOC, D.DEPTNO 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

might be preferred.